# Java ObjectStream 'StreamCorruptedException: Invalid type code: 00

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm learning java, digging into the basics of UDP/TCP networking. I'm trying to learn the basic outline of how Datagrams can be used to send multiple objects between client/server. I have a basic `ScratchObject`, `ScratchServer`, and `ScratchClient` classes as such:

**ScratchObject**

```
public class ScratchObj implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    ScratchObj(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

**ScratchServer**

```
public class ScratchServer {

public void listen() throws IOException {

    int port = 9268;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;


    // Listen for initial flag request
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    socket.receive(receivePacket);

    // Create Object and send
    // Open Socket to Client
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    ByteArrayOutputStream sendBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(sendBuffer);

    while(count < 5){

        // Get a random card
        ScratchObj obj = new ScratchObj("Test Object Name-" + count);
        System.out.println("Sending Object: " + obj);

        // Write card to output stream
        objOutStream.writeObject(obj);

        // Put object as bytes to output buffer + Send via socket
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                sendBuffer.toByteArray(),
                sendBuffer.size(),
                receivePacket.getAddress(),  // sender host/IP
                receivePacket.getPort());    // sender port
        socket.send(sendPacket);
        sendBuffer.flush();

        // Close stuff out
        count++;
    }
    objOutStream.close();
    sendBuffer.close();
    socket.close();

}
```

}

**ScratchClient**

```
public class ScratchClient {

public ScratchClient() throws SocketException {}

public void listen() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    byte[] flagBuffer = "-file".getBytes();
    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    int port = 9268;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    // Open socket, send initial request to server
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
            flagBuffer, flagBuffer.length, host, port);
    socket.send(packet);

    // Open socket to receive data
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    socket.receive(packet);

    // Create buffer, interpret as object
    ByteArrayInputStream receiveBuffer = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
    ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(receiveBuffer);
    ScratchObj sObj = (ScratchObj) objStream.readObject();

    while(sObj != null){
        System.out.println(sObj);
        sObj = (ScratchObj) objStream.readObject();
    }
}
```

}

I'm running drivers on my machine to instantiate the ScratchClient and ScratchServer classes. On the ScratchServer console, I see the following output:

```
Sending Object: TEST OBJECT NAME-0
Sending Object: TEST OBJECT NAME-1
Sending Object: TEST OBJECT NAME-2
Sending Object: TEST OBJECT NAME-3
Sending Object: TEST OBJECT NAME-4
```

On the ScratchClient, I see this:

```
TEST OBJECT NAME-0
```

Followed by this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1678)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:441)
    at client.ScratchClient.listen(ScratchClient.java:35)
    at client.ScratchClientDriver.main(ScratchClientDriver.java:9)
```

I *believe* the issue is in the ScratchClient file in these lines of code:

```
while(sObj != null){
    System.out.println(sObj);
    sObj = (ScratchObj) objStream.readObject();
}
```

It seems that I'm able to receive the first object, but I'm missing something to allow reception of the second. I've read the [Javadocs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html) but they didn't describe the send/receipt of multiple objects. Hoping someone would be kind enough to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You're only writing one object per datagram, so why are you trying to read more than one object from each datagram? And where did you get the idea that `readObject()` returning null should terminate a loop?

Comment: So this got closed out, though I didn't find the reference answer particularly helpful (I'm not using threads). However, I think your comment got me on the right track. I created a new DatagramPacket for each iteration in my loop and things worked well. Re: the `sObj != null` condition, clearly it never is `null` unless a null object is send. I'm new to Java, and wasn't sure the best-practice for that approach. I'd seen an empty `for` loop in a try-catch for an `EOFException` that I thought looked horrible.